# How to disable everything on underlying div while external div activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this side tab panel where i when i click on it, it will activate a external div, during that time, i want the underlying div to have all their events like hover over dropdown menu deactivated and stuff, basically they can't click on the underlying div to change page while the popup div activated.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10xr2uah/ , for now i only changed the opacity, but user still can hover over the dropdown and change page while popup panel is on, i tried stuff like

`$(".container").attr('disabled', 'disabled');` but it doesn't work

Also i have

```
$(function() {
   $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $(".log").html("panel sliding out");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
        $(".container").css("opacity", 0.3);

        $(".container").click(function() {
            $(this).unbind("click");
            $(".log").html("panel hide success");
            $("#toggle_content").hide();
            $(".container").css("opacity", 1);
        }); 
    });
```

});

how can i edit the code so that when i click on the tab, it will open, and when i click on it again, it will close with opacity returning to normal?

In case you are confused, basically i am trying to solve:
1) how to disable background div(disable dropdown expanding on hover) while popup div is activated
2) how to click on the tab again to return everything to normal.

Comment: have you checked for `$("item").prop("disabled", true);` ? It works most of the time.

Comment: try to use jquery's on & off. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use container's pseudo element `:before` to make a visual overlay. This way you don't have to add new elements to HTML:

```
.container.overlay-disable:before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, .6);
}
```

JS:

```
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    $(".log").html("panel sliding out");
    $("#toggle_content").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 350);
    $(".container").addClass("overlay-disable");
    $(".container").click(function () {
        $(".log").html("panel hide success");
        $("#toggle_content").hide();
        $(".container").removeClass("overlay-disable");
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/10xr2uah/3/

Comment: short question, it works well for my content, but doesn't work on images that are within the content, seems like the images will bypass the overlay class. How can i solve it?

Comment: Are images within container?

Comment: yes they are, i copy and pasted the dropdown menu below the images, both the top and bottom dropdown menu was successfully hidden but not the images in between.

Comment: I think you need to adjust z-index numbers for overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/10xr2uah/4/

Answer (score 2):

when i have s similar situation i created a simple overlay that covers the tab panel and stops triggering events over the tab

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class="overlay"></div> // create a overlay
        <div class="log_container sixteen columns">
            <p class="two column">Log:</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
            $(".log").html("panel sliding out");
            $("#toggle_content").animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            }, 350);
            $('.overlay').show();
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
     position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 65px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: white;
    }
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/10xr2uah/1/)**

Comment: works well, but i don't think this is the best way to do things.. hope i can get a better answer along the way! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let x of temp0.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  x.disabled = true;
}
```

where `temp0` is your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/10xr2uah/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mask"></div>
```

**CSS** changes

```
.mask{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    display:none;    
}
```

And changes for **JS** are as follows

```
$(function() {
  $('.mask').height(parseInt($('.log_container').height()+$('#navigation').height()));
   $("#toggle").click(function() {

        $(".log").html("panel sliding out");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
        $('.mask').show();

        $(".container").click(function() {
            $(this).unbind("click");
            $(".log").html("panel hide success");
            $("#toggle_content").hide();                
            $('.mask').hide();
        }); 
    });
```

});